# Hadoop suitability for recursive data processing

Tags: recursion, hadoop, mapreduce, bigdata

I have a filtering algorithm that needs to be applied recursively and I am not sure if MapReduce is suitable for this job. W/o giving too much away, I can say that each object that is being filtered is characterized by a collection if ordered list or queue.

1. The data is not huge, just about 250MB when I export from SQL to
   CSV.
2. The mapping step is simple: the head of the list contains an object that can classify the list as belonging to one of **N** mapping nodes. the filtration algorithm at each node works on the collection of lists assigned to the node and at the end of the filtration, either a list remains the same as before the filtration or the head of the list is removed.
3. The reduce function is simple too: all the map jobs' lists are brought together and may have to be written back to disk.
4. When all the **N** nodes have returned their output, the mapping step is repeated with this new set of data.

Note: **N** can be as much as 2000 nodes.
Simple, but it requires perhaps up to a 1000 recursions before the algorithm's termination conditions are met.

My question is would this job be suitable for Hadoop? If not, what are my options?

Comment: Are you trying to perform a [dropWhile](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools#itertools.dropwhile) operation over a large collection of lists, where for each list you remove the longest prefix of items that satisfy some predicate and return the remaining tail of the list?  If so, I would perform this in a single MapReduce job, performing the dropWhile operation in a loop inside the mapper.

Comment: It's a bit more complicated. It's an optimization problem and each mapped job solves a smaller optimization problem. The reduce step combines the output of all these smaller optimization problems and the process is repeated.

Answer (score 1):

The main strength of Hadoop is its ability to transparently distribute work on a large number of machines. In order to fully benefit from Hadoop your application has to be characterized, at least by the following three things:

1. work with large amounts of data (data which is distributed in the cluster of machines) - which would be impossible to store on one machine
2. be data-parallelizable (i.e. chunks of the original data can be manipulated independently from other chunks)
3. the problem which the application is trying to solve lends itself nicely to the MapReduce (scatter - gather) model.

It seems that out of these 3, your application has only the last 2 characteristics (with the observation that you are trying to recursively use a scatter - gather procedure - which means a large number of jobs - equal to the recursion depth; see last paragraph why this might not be appropriate for hadoop).

Given the amount of data you're trying to process, I don't see any reason why you wouldn't do it on a single machine, completely in memory. If you think you can benefit from processing that small amount of data in parallel, I would recommend focusing on multicore processing than on distributed data intensive processing. Of course, using the processing power of a networked cluster is tempting but this comes at a cost: mainly the time inefficiency given by the network communication (network being the most contended resource in a hadoop cluster) and by the I/O. In scenarios which are well-fitted to the Hadoop framework these inefficiency can be ignored because of the efficiency gained by distributing the data and the associated work on that data.

As I can see, you need 1000 jobs. The setup and the cleanup of all those jobs would be an unnecessary overhead for your scenario. Also, the overhead of network transfer is not necessary, in my opinion.

Comment: Your observation is right and to the point. trouble is, a large number of recursions is required for each of the **N** jobs i.e. spawn **N** jobs, let ALL of them finish take the output data  and repeat for potentially **M^2** recursions, **M** being the avg length of each list. On a single m/c, it's infeasible.

Answer (score 0):

Recursive algos are hard in the distributed systems since they can lead to a quick starvation. Any middleware that would work for that needs to support distributed continuations, i.e. the ability to make a "recursive" call without holding the resources (like threads) of the calling side.

[GridGain](http://www.gridgain.com) is one product that natively supports distributed continuations.

THe litmus test on distributed continuations: try to develop a naive fibonacci implementation in distributed context using recursive calls. Here's the GridGain's [example](https://github.com/gridgain/gridgain/blob/master/examples/java/org/gridgain/examples/continuation/GridContinuationExample.java) that implements this using continuations.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

Q&D, but I suggest you read a comparison of MongoDB and Hadoop:
http://www.osintegrators.com/whitepapers/MongoHadoopWP/index.html

Without knowing more, it's hard to tell.  You might want to try both.  Post your results if you do!